# error The argument type 'PdfImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation, flutter-packages

I am trying to make pdf from screenshot with screenshot and pdf plugins in flutter.

When I pass Uint8List to pdf creation function I am getting error at `PdfImage.file(pdf.document, bytes: screenShot`   **The argument type 'PdfImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'**   The code to convert to pdf is

```
Future getPdf(Uint8List screenShot) async {
    pw.Document pdf = pw.Document();
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (context) {
          return pw.Expanded(
              child: pw.Image(PdfImage.file(pdf.document, bytes: screenShot), fit: pw.BoxFit.contain)
          );
        },
      ),
    );
    File pdfFile = File('Your path + File name');
    pdfFile.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());
  }
```

and passing the screenshot to the pdf function is below

```
 Uint8List _imageFile;
screenshotController.capture().then((Uint8List image) {
                                            //Capture Done
                                            setState(() {
                                              _imageFile = image;
                                            });
                                          }).catchError((onError) {
                                            print(onError);
                                          });
                                          getPdf(_imageFile);
                                          },
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What about [MemoryImage](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/MemoryImage-class.html)?

Comment: @PeterKoltai sorry i don't get you!

Comment: Do you use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package?

Comment: @PeterKoltai yes that package is used for converting that screenshot to pdf that is part where i got the error,  you can see it in the above code.

Comment: This package has a method called MemoryImage, I linked it, unlike `pw.Image` it accepts `Uint8List` as input, give it a try.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Can you add this in my code above?

Comment: Try: `child: pw.MemoryImage(screenShot)`

Comment: @PeterKoltai The argument type 'MemoryImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Future getPdf(Uint8List screenShot) async {
    pw.Document pdf = pw.Document();
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
        build: (context) {
          return pw.Expanded(
              // change this line to this:
              child: pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(screenshot), fit: pw.BoxFit.contain),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
    File pdfFile = File('Your path + File name');
    pdfFile.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());
  }
```

Comment: the pw.memoryImage should be MemoryImage. The M should be in cap. So "pw.MemoryImage"